# How to make an ordered Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, comparator

```
 public void sort1(){
    Comparator<OCell> byOrder = new Comparator<OCell>(){

        public int compare(OCell c1, OCell c2){
            return c1.getData() < c2.getData();
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(list, byOrder);
    print();
}
static OLinkedList<Integer> list = new OLinkedList<Integer>();
```

This is what I've come up so far but it's not working. Any help?

Comment: You need to better explain your task. Do you want to sort a list and print, or order entries while putting them in a list?

Answer (score 3):

A `Comparator.compare` method must return an integer, but your expression `c1.getData() < c2.getData()` is a boolean expression. You must fix your method, perhaps something as follows:

```
c1.getData() > c2.getData() ? 1 : (c1.getData() < c2.getData() ? -1 : 0)
```

Comment: If those are just integers, you might as well use the builtin `Integer.compare()` method

Comment: @fge Good point. Provided that it is JDK 7, because I think this method didn't exist before.